# How to write values in Ignition SCADA using MQTT Engine

Tags: mqtt, ignition, scada-ignition

I am setting up an application which publishes values to Ignition SCADA through MQTT using the SparkPlugB specification.

However, now I want to go in the other direction. I want Ignition to be able to change values and my application can read those changes.

The problem arises when I try to actually write to values in Ignition, sometimes nothing happens and sometimes it says that I cannot write these values.

What configuration / SparkPlugB specification needs to be set in order for Ignition to be able to write these values?

I have tried reading the SparkPlugB spec but so far found nothing that aids me in my quest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @magni_mar looks like the method described in https://docs.chariot.io/display/CLD80/Enable+Device+Writes+from+Ignition could fix the issue.

1. Start by browsing to your Ignition Gateway's web UI and select 'Configure'.  The default URL is:  http://127.0.0.1:8088
2. The default username / password is setup by the user during installation .  Once in the Configuration menu select 'MQTT ENGINE -> Settings' on the left navigation bar (towards the bottom).
3. Once there, you'll see the following under the 'General' tab.  There are two options: "Block Node Commands" and "Block Device Commands".  Make sure they are both disabled (not checked) and click 'Save Changes'